# RETURNING equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pdo

I need to find an equivalent in MySQL for the RETURNING functionality in PostgreSQL (for INSERT INTO). LAST_INSERT_ID() does not work because the id is not auto-incrementing, and is instead generated by a subquery. Because of the delay between the single queries allowed by PDO, I would like to implement this in a single line without table-locking so as to keep the table available.

Answer (score 2):

How about to add a dummy auto-incremental primary key? Then, the process will not be done by single query, but can be done without explicit table-locking.

1. Insert a row.
2. Get PK via LAST_INSERT_ID().
3. Fetch the row with result of [2].

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I totally misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: There are certainly a number of changes in table design that could eliminate the problem, but the database belongs to a separately maintained application, and I would like to avoid changing its structure.